# Why this code is giving exception

Tags: java

Why i am getting this exception?

I am new to java and stackoverflow

```
ArrayList<A> a = new ArrayList<A>();
ArrayList<B> b = new ArrayList<B>();

a.add(new A("A"));
a.add(new A("B"));
a.add(new A("C"));

b.add(new B(new A("A"), "a"));
b.add(new B(new A("B"), "b"));
b.add(new B(new A("C"), "c"));

System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);

bIterator = b.iterator();
while(bIterator.hasNext()) {
    b.add(new B(bIterator.next(), "a"));
}
```

error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

Comment: Your first port of call should *always* be [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html): *"The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: **if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created**, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, **the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException**. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly..."* *(my emphasis)*

Answer (score 5):

You get this exception because you iterate over a list and modify it at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

> Below piece of code is creating problem, because you are iterating
>   over a list and modifying it at the same time.

```
while(bIterator.hasNext()) {
    b.add(new B(bIterator.next(), "a"));
}
```

[ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
while(bIterator.hasNext()) {
    b.add(new B(bIterator.next(), "a"));
}
```

If you see carefully above lines, you are iterating over that list and trying to add some more elements at same time.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown because you are modifying an ArrayList when iterating it.
However, there are List implementations that support this, such as [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).